# Create collection with selected data

Tags: php, laravel

I have this code:

```
$terms = $this->model
            ->where('course_terms.is_active', true)
            ->where(function ($query) use ($dateFrom, $dateTo) {
                if ($dateFrom != "" && $dateTo == "") {
                    $query->whereDate('starting_at', '>=', $dateFrom);
                } elseif ($dateFrom == "" && $dateTo != "") {
                    $query->whereDate('starting_at', '<=', $dateTo);
                } else {
                    $query->whereBetween('starting_at', [$dateFrom, $dateTo]);
                }
            })
            ->select(['courses.short_name AS short_name', 'course_terms.*'])
            ->leftJoin('courses', 'courses.id', '=', 'course_terms.course_id')
            ->orderBy('starting_at', 'asc')
            ->get();
        
        $termsArray = [];
        foreach ($terms as $term)
        {
            dump($term);
}
```

It's return me:

```
 Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#1814 ▼
  #items: array:3 [▼
    0 => App\Models\CourseTerm {#1815 ▼
      #fillable: array:8 [▶]
      #dates: array:5 [▶]
      #casts: array:6 [▶]
      #appends: array:1 [▶]
      #connection: "mysql"
      #table: "course_terms"
      #primaryKey: "id"
      #keyType: "int"
      +incrementing: true
      #with: []
      #withCount: []
      #perPage: 15
      +exists: true
      +wasRecentlyCreated: false
      #attributes: array:16 [▼
        "short_name" => "nazwa 1"
        "id" => 2
        "starting_at" => "2020-12-22"
        "days" => 123
        "course_id" => 1
        "max_participants" => 12312
        "additional_notes" => "Fajny kurs 1213"
        "is_active" => 1
        "is_confirmed" => 1
        "created_at" => "2020-12-14 12:24:37"
        "updated_at" => "2020-12-14 12:39:22"
        "deleted_at" => null
        "created_by" => 1
        "updated_by" => 1
        "deleted_by" => null
        "diary_generated_at" => "2020-12-14 13:40:40"
      ]
      #original: array:16 [▶]
      #changes: []
      #classCastCache: []
      #dateFormat: null
      #dispatchesEvents: []
      #observables: []
      #relations: []
      #touches: []
      +timestamps: true
      #hidden: []
      #visible: []
      #guarded: array:1 [▶]
      #forceDeleting: false
    }
    1 => App\Models\CourseTerm {#1816 ▼
      #fillable: array:8 [▶]
      #dates: array:5 [▶]
      #casts: array:6 [▶]
      #appends: array:1 [▶]
      #connection: "mysql"
      #table: "course_terms"
      #primaryKey: "id"
      #keyType: "int"
      +incrementing: true
      #with: []
      #withCount: []
      #perPage: 15
      +exists: true
      +wasRecentlyCreated: false
      #attributes: array:16 [▼
        "short_name" => "nazwa 1"
        "id" => 1
        "starting_at" => "2020-12-25"
        "days" => 12
        "course_id" => 1
        "max_participants" => 12
        "additional_notes" => "Fajny kurs"
        "is_active" => 1
        "is_confirmed" => 1
        "created_at" => "2020-12-14 11:34:30"
        "updated_at" => "2020-12-14 12:39:26"
        "deleted_at" => null
        "created_by" => 1
        "updated_by" => 1
        "deleted_by" => null
        "diary_generated_at" => "2020-12-14 12:39:26"
      ]
      #original: array:16 [▶]
      #changes: []
      #classCastCache: []
      #dateFormat: null
      #dispatchesEvents: []
      #observables: []
      #relations: []
      #touches: []
      +timestamps: true
      #hidden: []
      #visible: []
      #guarded: array:1 [▶]
      #forceDeleting: false
    }
    2 => App\Models\CourseTerm {#1817 ▼
      #fillable: array:8 [▶]
      #dates: array:5 [▶]
      #casts: array:6 [▶]
      #appends: array:1 [▶]
      #connection: "mysql"
      #table: "course_terms"
      #primaryKey: "id"
      #keyType: "int"
      +incrementing: true
      #with: []
      #withCount: []
      #perPage: 15
      +exists: true
      +wasRecentlyCreated: false
      #attributes: array:16 [▼
        "short_name" => "nazwa 2"
        "id" => 3
        "starting_at" => "2020-12-27"
        "days" => 12
        "course_id" => 2
        "max_participants" => 12
        "additional_notes" => "kurs na 100"
        "is_active" => 1
        "is_confirmed" => 1
        "created_at" => "2020-12-14 15:31:44"
        "updated_at" => null
        "deleted_at" => null
        "created_by" => 1
        "updated_by" => 1
        "deleted_by" => null
        "diary_generated_at" => "2020-12-14 14:32:01"
      ]
      #original: array:16 [▶]
      #changes: []
      #classCastCache: []
      #dateFormat: null
      #dispatchesEvents: []
      #observables: []
      #relations: []
      #touches: []
      +timestamps: true
      #hidden: []
      #visible: []
      #guarded: array:1 [▶]
      #forceDeleting: false
    }
  ]
}
```

It's work fine.

I need show in my blade something like this (by course_id):

- nazwa 1 (short_name) has terms:  2020-12-22 , 2020-12-25 (starting_at)
- nazwa 2 (short_name) has terms: 2020-12-27 (starting_at)

How can I make it?

I need collection with this form: 'name'=> nazwa 1, [2020-12-22 , 2020-12-25].
How can I make this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try manipulating via Collection methods

```php
$terms->groupBy('short_name')  
  ->map(function($records){
    return $records->map(function($term){
        return $term->starting_at;
    })->all();
  })->all();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
$terms = $this->model
        ->where('course_terms.is_active', true)
        ->where(function ($query) use ($dateFrom, $dateTo) {
            if ($dateFrom != "" && $dateTo == "") {
                $query->whereDate('starting_at', '>=', $dateFrom);
            } elseif ($dateFrom == "" && $dateTo != "") {
                $query->whereDate('starting_at', '<=', $dateTo);
            } else {
                $query->whereBetween('starting_at', [$dateFrom, $dateTo]);
            }
        })
        ->select(['courses.short_name AS short_name', 'course_terms.*'])
        ->leftJoin('courses', 'courses.id', '=', 'course_terms.course_id')
        ->orderBy('starting_at', 'asc')
        ->groupBy('created_by') // or your common column by which you identify person ('nazwa 1' as per example)
        ->get();
```

So it groups 2 array in one based on `groupby` key. And show data according that.

Comment: It's return me 2 courses, without terms :(

Comment: Can you please post your collection dump after this try.